# Python: Pyplot in loop --> curves are cumulated per iteration, not separately plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot e.g. 10 lists with each list being represented by a single curve and saved in a separate file, so nothing special.

Problem is that the plotted curves are not deleted after each iteration, so that in each iteration/plot/file the new curve is simply added to the curves of previous iterations.

```
list1 = [...]
...
list10 = [...]
all_Lists = [list1, ..., list10]

for i in range(10):
    pyplot.plot(all_Lists[i])
    pyplot.savefig(...)
```

file1 has 1 curve / list1 plotted.

file2 has 2 curves / list1+list2 plotted.
...

Would appreciate, if someone could explain, how to get a single curve per plot, using a for-loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that you dont use the OO interface. Pyplot is convenient but handles a lot of things in the background making you unaware of whats really going on. In your example you create a figure and axes on-the-fly and keep plotting in that same axes.

Clearing the axes before plotting would solve your issue, try adding `pyplot.cla()` as the first line of your loop.

I would prefer making a figure and axes object:

```
all_Lists = [list(np.random.randn(30).cumsum()) for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for n, curv in enumerate(all_Lists):
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(curv)
    fig.savefig()
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response!
plotting on-the-fly might not be the problem, since len(list) should be on x-axis and val(listItem) on y-axis, which seems to work properly.

the term "flush" just came to my mind, googled it and found this fct:
gcf().clear()

Inserted after pyplot.savefig() and the problem seems to be solved. Can you confirm that this is a proper solution, too?

Comment: @dax5 That will also work, but that is less efficient than @RutgerKassies solution, as you are clearing the _figure_ rather than the _axes_. With your solution you have to re-create the `Axes` instance for every iteration, since you are clearing it from the `Figure` (which is what `gcf().clear()` does). Since you are not changing the layout of your plot (number of subplots, placement of subplots etc.), it is more efficient to clear out the `Axes` instance instead. Then you have to create the `Axes` instance only _once_.